# A verb to describe defensive behavior/action in an attempt to deny embarrassment

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a verb/term to describe someone's aggressive argument with twisted logic in an attempt to cover up his/her embarrassment arising from his/her mistake.
Similar to projecting. Are there other words which can be used to describe such behavior more accurately?

Comment: "Saving face" does this.

Answer (score -1):

**overcompensate** (v. intransative)

> To take excessive measures to correct or make amends for
> an error, weakness, etc.; to compensate excessively; (Psychology) to
> behave in an exaggerated manner in an attempt to make up for what is
> felt as a weakness or defect in one's character. OED

> *Psychology*
> To react to a real or imagined physical or
> psychological defect with a conscious or unconscious exaggerated drive
> to compensate for it [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/overcompensate)

---

> *Strategy 4: denial and arrogance*: children may **overcompensate** for feeling inadequate and ashamed in social situations by denying
> that there is a problem and pointing the finger of blame outwards.
> They see themselves as "above the rules' and have difficulty admitting
> to being wrong or making a mistake, often arguing their case very
> skillfully. [Trevor Powell; *Recognising Autism and Asperger's
> Syndrome*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Recognising_Autism_and_Asperger_s_Syndro/tDAXEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=overcompensate%20for%20mistakes%20by%20arguing&pg=PT34&printsec=frontcover)

> There is also a tendency within the intelligence community to
> **overcompensate** for errors by exaggerating the possibility of opposite outcomes. [M. A. Goodman; *Failure of Intelligence*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Failure_of_Intelligence/TYc-vuU9Jl4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=overcompensate%20for%20mistakes%20by%20arguing&pg=PA112&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I suggest you'd need to provide several, much stronger examples to demonstrate "overcompensate" meaning "defensive behavior/action in an attempt to deny embarrassment". The Question seeks a quality but in the context, "overcompensate" works only as a measure of quantity, and then only in combination not stated.

Comment: @ColdCutTrio I suggest there isn't any single word with that meaning, nor anything very close to it… the less so if it needs to be "…similar to projecting". Can you show two or three example sentences whose gaps this might fill?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin A behavior, such as overcompensation, result from several different motivations, denying embarrassment can be one. The cause of the embarrassment may, in turn, have any one of a number of causes, including mistakes made. People don't have explanatory signs on their foreheads. There isn't a specific behavior caused by the embarrassment over forgetting appointments and another for phone numbers.

Comment: No. Overcompensation is by definition a result of a failure to respond appropriately, not an attempt to deny embarrassment

Overcompensation could well be a response to finding oneself in hundreds of situations, including the possibility of embarrassment… but that will never come close to making it a verb to describe defensive behavior/action in an attempt to deny embarrassment.

Do you see the difference?